# PHP Pass Variable To Popup Page via Href Link From SQL Query

Tags: php, html, ajax, href

As the title says I'm trying to pass a variable as pmntid from to a DIV, on the same page, for a popup page via href. The html link is as follows:

```
<td class="listingTextLeft">
 <a href="#?pmntid=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"onclick="document.getElementById('pmntDetailPopup').style.display='block';document.getElementById('pmntDetailFade').style.display='block'"
    class="green">
    <?php echo $row[20] ?>
 </a>
</td>
```

Hovering over the link shows the correct structure for the variable, i.e. pmntid=5 and when the link is clicked it brings up the popup in the DIV `pmntDetailPopup`, however when using `$_GET['pmntid']` there is no value.

The query runs as it should as I get correct results when using it in other areas on the html page. Not sure if it makes a difference but have `session_start();` at the top of the page.

Have searched through Stackoverflow and other sites for an answer but just cannot spot what I am doing wrong and other suggested solutions I've tried do not work.

As suggested I've remove the #, however it still did not pass the pmntid to the popup and the popup window only stays open for a matter of seconds.

Should add that I've tried redirecting it to a new php page and it shows the correct pmntid so it is picking up the variable okay, just not passing it to my div.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the # in front of your url so the $_GET can't catch it.
Try to remove it or parse the entire url looking for your parameter.

Comment: thankyou that sort of worked, it now has a pmntid but now have 2 other problems, the popup window disappears after a few seconds (putting # back in stops this) and have to select the link twice to get the correct id, it appears to be 'keeping' the previous selected until the second selection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try storing as session variable?

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['pmntid']= $row[0];
```

Then on the popup page do

```
session_start();
$pmntid = $_SESSION['pmntid'];
```